# set variable to NULL if nested query returns no results

Tags: sql, syntax, subquery

Suppose you have the following query. If the nested query returns `NULL`(0 results), the stored procedure crashes with the following error mentioned below.  I found out I can re-write the code in the Alternative query below, but I'm wanting to find an easier syntax to write it.  I have about 10 of these, and some have multiple nested queries.  Is there an easier way to write them?  I'm not an expert in SQL, so I'm always looking for suggestions! Thanks.

**Query (that sometimes crashes):**

```
SET @sampleid = (
    SELECT 
        [sampleid]
    FROM [sample]
    WHERE [identifyingnumber] = @sample_identifyingnumber
```

**Error from query:**

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery
follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

**Alternative query that never crashes:**

```
IF 
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT([sampleid])
    FROM [sample]
    WHERE [identifyingnumber] = @sample_identifyingnumber
) = 0
BEGIN
SET @sampleid = NULL
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @sampleid =
(
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT [sampleid]
    FROM [sample]
    WHERE [identifyingnumber] = @sample_identifyingnumber
)
END
```

===============

**Example that's more complex:**

```
SET @testcodeid = (
    SELECT 
        [testcodeid]
    FROM [testcode]
    WHERE [testcode].[name] = (
        SELECT [test_code]
        FROM [ws_test_request]
        WHERE [client_id] = @clientid
          AND [sample_specimen_id] = @sample_identifyingnumber
    )
);
```

Comment: Except, the error you've mentioned is the one that occurs when multiple results are returned, not zero, and is fixed by you adding the "distinct" keyword into your alternate query...

Comment: Once you've scrubbed the data, consider fixing the problem to prevent re-occurrence by adding a foreign key with the `ON DELETE SET NULL` referential action (or ideally remove nullable columns from your database entirely ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT @sampleid = [sampleid]
FROM [sample]
WHERE [identifyingnumber] = @sample_identifyingnumber
```

Comment: OMG.. that is so simple!  Thanks--you're a genius.  If you can tell me how to give a badge, I'll give you one.  I've never done it before.

Answer (score 0):

You set to NULL the records for which do not exist records in sample_table with identifyingnumber equal to sample_identifyingnumber:

```
UPDATE my_table
   SET sampleid = NULL
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT 'X'
             FROM sample_table
            WHERE identifyingnumber = sample_identifyingnumber);
```

You set to MIN (DISTINCT sampleid) the field sampleid for which exist in sample_table records where identifying_number = sample_identifyingnumber:

```
UPDATE my_table
   SET sampleid =
          (SELECT MIN (DISTINCT sampleid)
             FROM sample_table
            WHERE identifyingnumber = sample_identifyingnumber)
 WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 'X'
             FROM sample_table
            WHERE identifying_number = sample_identifyingnumber);
```

I have written MIN (DISTINCT ...) in case we find more sampleids corresponding to the same identifyingnumber: in this unlucky case, I take the MINIMUM of the X (with X strictly > 1) different sampleids.

I need two updates instead of one.

Comment: If you're taking `MIN`, you don't need `DISTINCT`